# iOS Firebase Push Notifications not receive in device using obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase-cloud-messaging

Integrate Firebase cloud messaging in my application. Successfully install pod and get all the framework. I want to get the refreshedToken for my device and send the notification and receive in my device, and want to track all the button click in my app.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
        // iOS 7.1 or earlier
        UIRemoteNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:allNotificationTypes];
    } else {
        // iOS 8 or later
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }

    // [START configure_firebase]
    [FIRApp configure];
    // [END configure_firebase]

    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:)
                                                 name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];

    return YES;
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // Print message ID.
    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[@"gcm.message_id"]);

    // Pring full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
}

- (void)connectToFcm {
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Connected to FCM.");
        }
    }];
}



- (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Note that this callback will be fired everytime a new token is generated, including the first
    // time. So if you need to retrieve the token as soon as it is available this is where that
    // should be done.
    NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
    NSLog(@"InstanceID token: %@", refreshedToken);

    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    [self connectToFcm];

    // TODO: If necessary send token to appliation server.
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];

    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self connectToFcm];
}
```

I'm using this code in app delegate. Got these waring in my code. How can I fix this issues. new for development help me.

> WARNING: Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy is disabled. To log deep link campaigns manually, call the methods in FIRAnalytics+AppDelegate.h.
>           FCMAPP[496:56073] Configuring the default app.
>             Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"
>             FIRMessaging library version 1.1.0
>             Firebase Analytics v.3200000 started
>             To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled 
>             FIRMessaging registration is not ready with auth credentials
>           FCMAPP[496:56073] Unable to connect to FCM. Error Domain=com.google.fcm Code=501 "(null)"

Answer (score 2):

Use the following Swift code.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *)
    {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions([.Badge, .Sound, .Alert])          { (granted, error) in
            if granted
            {
                //self.registerCategory()
            }
         }
         // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
         FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
    }
    else
    {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =  UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert,.Badge,.Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }          
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()        
    //Configuring Firebase
    FIRApp.configure()
    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification), name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification, object: nil)     
     return true
}

//Receive Remote Notification on Background
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
{
    FIRMessaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)
{
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Sandbox)
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Prod)
}

func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification)
{
    if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()
    {
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
    }
    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    connectToFcm()
}

func connectToFcm()
{
    FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion { (error) in
        if (error != nil)
        {
            print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Connected to FCM.")
        }
    }
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication)
{            
    connectToFcm()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up the application correctly on the Firebase dashboard?

I have encountered this error before, as the Cloud Messaging settings aren't too obvious on the Firebase console.

1. Open the Firebase console. Click the cog next to your application name and go on "Project Settings".
2. Select the cloud messaging tab. You'll need to add your iOS APNS certificates here to successfully send push messages (One for development, one for production).

I was getting this error as I hadn't correctly uploaded my apps certificates.

**Update:**

Another reason for this error that i've encountered this error is that the Firebase SDK sometimes can't obtain the APNS token from apple itself. To resolve this, i've obtained the token manually:

First register for remote notifications:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

...

  // Register for remote notifications.
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

}
```

When the APNS token is returned, manually set it on the Firebase instance:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {

NSLog(@"Registered for notification device token: %@", devToken);

[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:devToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeUnknown];

[self connectToFcm];

const void *devTokenBytes = [devToken bytes];

}
```

Should then successfully be able to connect to Firebase cloud messaging:

```
- (void)connectToFcm {

NSLog(@"Connecting to FCM...");

[[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Connected to FCM.");
    }
}];
}
```

If you cannot obtain the APNS token this way, there is something wrong with your push notification setup on the apple member center. Have you generated a developer/release APNS certificate and added them to your provision profile?

Comment: i send the notification from firebase console it should display in my Xcode console successfully. But i dnt get push notification message in my device. how to fix tis issues.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a better solution. I recall that I also had this problem as Firebox couldn't obtain an APNS token from apple itself.

Comment: sorry i can't get u clearly.. what want to do. please make the change in my above code. still i can't get the push notification in my device. what wrong I'm doing in dnt know help me.

Comment: Just add `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];` to the bottom of your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. And then check if you receive a token in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`.

Comment: ya i device the device token like this <573eb8a4 099d5d83 67de7e3b dac1748c efa56fa3 8bf03be0 84172dcc b27a8b49>  and i copy this device token put firebase notification page. select the single device and paste it type the msg and send it. got the  message in console not in device. how to fix this.

Comment: So now in your code if you manually set the token on the Firebase instance with `[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:devToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeUnknown];` and then call `connectToFcm` again, you should be able to send push notifications to the device.

Comment: <573eb8a4 099d5d83 67de7e3b dac1748c efa56fa3 8bf03be0 84172dcc b27a8b49> copy and paste the this FCM registration token in firebase notification page. the message send fail. what to do?

Comment: Unable to connect to FCM. Error Domain=com.google.fcm Code=2001 "(null)"  also got these warning.. help me..

Comment: @UmaMadhavi any solution found?

Comment: @Mamta . This is resolved for me ,the issue is with the payload

Comment: @UmaMadhavi Thanks! I will check and get back